# FPDF prints one extra blank page

Tags: php, printing, fpdf

I am using `FPDF` to view/print data in `PHP`.
There is only one page I can see on my browser. But, When I try to print that page. I get one extra blank page from printer. Why `FPDF` submits one extra page every time? Is there any setting that I need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is due to the FPDF software and not the bi-directional printing driver associated with your printer?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: I don't know what does it mean?

Comment: Please investigate the bi-directional printing issue as it's generally what causes blank pages to be printed for no reason. It is against SOO rules to link to google, but it's definitely the best place to look regarding this matter.